# How can I put a child div in the top left corner of the document. even above the parents div?

Tags: html, css

I made 3 columns with the bootstrap framework. In the second column there is a div with some text. I would like to move that div to the top left corner of the document (not on the top left corner of the parent).

I cannot just add a div above the columns or add jquery or javascript because I am using other software. It is very stricted and I can only add custom CSS to it.

An example. The purple div should be on the space of the left arrow:
[image: An example. The purple div should be on the space of the left arrow]

I tried position absolute but with no success.
The code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./example.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"><h3>Title 1 - col-sm-4</h3></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
        <div class="section-topleft">
            <h3>This div should be on the top left corner of the document</h3>
        </div>
        <h3>Title 2 - col-sm-4</h3></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;"><h3>Title 3 - col-sm-4</h3></div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```css
.section-topleft{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: purple;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

I also do not want position: fixed. I am really curious if this is even possible. If it's not possible it's also fine.

[In the real example it does not work yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ul8wR.png)

[Here you can see the css of the div with class "test". The div that should be placed on the top left corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo0D5.png)

So here is the code of the HTML from the 3rd row (relevant html):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
      <!-- Nav (Logged in) -->
          <div class="main-logo">
            <a href="https://google.com">
            <img src="https://leaddyno-client-images.s3.amazonaws.com/c5204ac1a6274432acd0d657ad3679ea55f93d49/df60389c3caec18e6d856beca7c8_logo_black.png">
            </a>
          </div>
        <div class="navi-left">
            <ul>
    <li class="active">
      <a href="/affiliate">
        <span id="affiliate-nav-homepage"><span class="default">Home Page</span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/affiliate/content">
          <span id="affiliate-nav-marketing-materials"><span class="default">Marketing Materials</span></span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/affiliate/analytics">
          <span id="affiliate-nav-analytics"><span class="default">Analytics</span></span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/affiliate/invite">
          <span id="affiliate-nav-invite-others"><span class="default">Invite Others</span></span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/affiliate/children">
          <span id="affiliate-nav-your-network"><span class="default">Your Network</span></span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/affiliate/subids">
          <span id="affiliate-nav-sub-ids"><span class="default">SubIDs/Channels</span></span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/affiliate/landing_pages">
          <span id="affiliate-nav-landing-pages"><span class="default">Landing Pages</span></span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/affiliate/commission_details">
          <span id="affiliate-nav-commission-details"><span class="default">Commissions</span></span>
        </a>
      </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="navi-mobile-lower">
      <li>
        <i>
          <hr>
        </i>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="/affiliate/create_password">Create Password</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/affiliate/account_email">Update Account Email</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/affiliate/update_paypal">Update Paypal Email</a>
      </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/ext/affiliates/sign_out">Log Out</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="main-content">

        <!-- header -->
          <div class="custom-header">
            <div class="default-title" id="default-title">
                <figure><img src="https://leaddyno-client-images.s3.amazonaws.com/c5204ac1a6274432acd0d657ad3679ea55f93d49/374c2ace96edb5866ba9e7aa079bbc202232c4e8_Brand%20advocates%20banner%20%283%29.png" data-image="foo"></figure>
            </div>
          </div>


            <div>
              <div class="v2-alerts">
                

              </div>
              <div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-3" style="
    position: static;
">
    <div class="left-panel">
      <div>
        <div class="test">
<h1>test</h1>
</div>






<p>We are excited to have you as part of the studio team!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="right-panel">


            <div id="sharing-div">
              


  <div class="sharing-section top-to-bottom">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="title">
          <span id="affiliate-link-title"><span class="default">Your Referral Link</span></span>
        </div>


          <div class="aff-link">
          <span><i>
            http://studio.com?afmc=1b
          </i></span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div>

                <div class="pull-right">
                  <a class="copy-link" data-clipboard-text="http://studio.com?afc=1b">copy&nbsp;link</a>
                </div>

        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



<div class="sharing-section top-to-bottom">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="title">
        <span id="primary-social-links-title"><span class="default">your primary social links</span></span>
        <div class="pull-right">
          <a href="/affiliate/content">view all links</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="links">
          <div class="share-btn">
            <a data-share-type="email" data-link-id="9937727" href="/share/email">
              <div>
                <img src="/assets/primary-email-c415b75ea87907f28155ecb8b66b5fc42686c773f6315e8a9151d8b61dbe385c.png">
              </div>
              Email
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="share-btn">
            <a href="/share/facebook" target="_blank" data-share-type="facebook" data-link-id="9937727">
              <div>
                <img src="/assets/primary-facebook-70e1f3176145c920e2423ffe0c06a15eece6e56cd51172582ea4d5571e0b0ab3.png">
              </div>
              Facebook
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="share-btn">
            <a data-share-type="twitter" data-link-id="9937727" target="_blank" href="/share/tweet">
              <div>
                <img src="/assets/primary-twitter-2130572d07fd2cd1604a59dd16498c4e267ddf5c8ed1a82fcc826f7c6511dee0.png">
              </div>
              Twitter
            </a>
          </div>
          <div id="whatsapp_share" class="share-btn">
            <a data-share-type="whatsapp" data-link-id="9937727" target="_blank" href="/share/whatsapp">
              <div>
                <img src="/assets/primary-whatsapp-283a25d6a61b76686118d7f2f5866a0ba21c520ff4404a3b248523b7b7d396bd.png">
              </div>
              Whatsapp
            </a>
          </div>
          <div id="text_share" class="share-btn">
            <a data-share-type="text" data-link-id="9937727" target="_blank" href="/share/text">
              <div>
                <img src="/assets/primary-sms-2ee17bddcfbb89a98c68fdcf8282df2e5920c135ebe62595e77dc0cfc6a0622c.png">
              </div>
              Text
            </a>
          </div>
          <div id="linked_in_share" class="share-btn">
            <a data-share-type="linkedin" data-link-id="9937727" target="_blank" href="/share/linkedin">
              <div>
                <img src="/assets/primary-linkedin-5bc3ba7bbfda5051d5d0d82ebc9b397ac17778b21fa7936ba7b0db3bbbc22d92.png">
              </div>
              LinkedIn
            </a>
          </div>
        <div class="share-btn">
          <a ic-action="slideToggle" ic-target="#instagram-sharing-instructions" data-share-type="instagram" data-link-id="9937727" ic-trigger-on="default">
            <div>
              <img src="/assets/primary-instagram-826dae8b5dbccbce3a5a2e4ed0936c96fb6a24e3eb32006f3e5ebf4c51e9dc32.png">
            </div>
            Instagram
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="instagram-sharing-instructions" style="display: none;">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="fs18">
      <span id="affiliate-instagram-sharing-instructions"><span class="default">Instagram Sharing Instructions</span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <ol>
      <li>
        <span class="instagram-badge">1</span>
        <a class="copy-link" data-clipboard-text="http://studio.com?afmc=1b">copy&nbsp;link</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="instagram-badge">2</span>
        <a id="instagram-launch" class="" href="https://instagram.com/_n/mainfeed/" target="_blank"><span></span><b>Click here to launch Instagram</b></a>
        <script>
          $(function(){
            if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
              $("#instagram-launch").attr('href', "instagram://");
            } else if(navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i)) {
              $("#instagram-launch").attr('href', "intent://instagram.com/_n/mainfeed/#Intent;package=com.instagram.android;scheme=https;end")
            } else {
              $("#instagram-launch").attr('href', "https://instagram.com/_n/mainfeed/");
              $("#instagram-launch").attr('target', "_blank")
            }
          })
        </script>
      </li>
      <li><span class="instagram-badge">3</span>Paste the link into your Profile, Story or Reels</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>


            </div>

            <!--<div class="divider"></div>-->

            <div>
              <div class="title">
  <span id="your-progress-title"><span class="default">Your Progress</span></span>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 aff-progress">
    <div class="aff-progress-digit">
      <b>2</b>
    </div>

    <div class="aff-progress-label">
      <span>
      <span id="affiliate-visitors-title"><span class="default">Friends have visited us</span></span>
    </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 aff-progress">
    <div class="aff-progress-digit">
      <b>0</b>
    </div>

    <div class="aff-progress-label">
      <span>
      <span id="affiliate-sign-up-title"><span class="default">Friends have signed up with us</span></span>
    </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 aff-progress">
    <div class="aff-progress-digit">
      <b>0</b>
    </div>

    <div class="aff-progress-label">
      <span>
      <span id="affiliate-purchase-title"><span class="default">Purchases made by friends</span></span>
    </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

            </div>


            <div class="divider"></div>

            <div>
              <div class="title">
  <span id="affiliate-payments-title"><span class="default">Your Payments</span></span>
</div>

<div class="dash-instructions">
  <p>You will receive a 30% commission for each referral. For monthly and annual subscriptions, you will receive recurring commissions as long as the member is subscribed.&nbsp;</p>
</div>

<div class="table-scrollable-wrapper">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <span id="affiliate-payments-compensation"><span class="default">Compensation</span></span>
      </th>
      <th>
        <span id="affiliate-payments-commissions-due"><span class="default">Due</span></span>
      </th>
      <th>
        <span id="affiliate-payments-commissions-upcoming"><span class="default">Upcoming</span></span>
      </th>
      <th>
        <span id="affiliate-payments-commissions-paid"><span class="default">Paid</span></span>
      </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="text-muted text-center">
          <span style="opacity: 0.5;"> nothing to show yet </span>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



            </div>
          </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the css(most of the important css is from bootstrap itself):

```css
body {
    background: #ffffff url(https://forge.swap-studio.com/assets/bg-polygon-dd7097463c1102fbf7fe55f6e00595256861740bba73750be91902f955f41f1e.png) no-repeat bottom center; /* fallback for old browsers */
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
  }

  .grad-text {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #555555 0, #555555 70%);
  }

  a{
      color: #002929;
  }

  /*.aff-link {*/
    /*border: 1px solid #002929;*/
  /*}*/

  /*.aff-link-2 {*/
    /*border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;*/
  /*}*/

  .aff-link-2 .copy-link {
    background-color: #cdcdcd;
    border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  }

  .aff-link-2 .btn-alt {
    color: #cdcdcd !important;
  }

  .copy-link {
    background-color: #002929;
    border: 1px solid #002929;
  }

  .copy-link-wide {
      background-color: #002929;
      border: 1px solid #002929;
  }

  .aff-progress b {
    color: #002929;
  }

  .change-url {
    color: #002929;
  }

  .change-url-field .btn {
    background-color: #002929;
  }

  .change-url-field .btn-alt {
    /*background-color: #002929;*/
  }

  .aff-invite input {
    border: 1px solid #002929;
  }

  .dot {
    border: (10 / 5) solid #002929;
  }

  #affiliate-invite-who {
    color: #002929;
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }

  .dash-primary-color {
    color: #002929 !important;
  }

  .button-primary {
    background-color: #002929;
    border: 1px solid #002929;
  }

  .email-input {
    border: 1px solid #002929;
  }

  .button-primary-fullwidth {
    background-color: #002929;
    border: 1px solid #002929;
    /*border-bottom: 3px solid #cdcdcd >;*/
  }

  .button-primary-flat-fullwidth {
    color: #002929;
    border: 1px solid #002929;
  }

  .comp-stats-figure {
      color: #002929;
  }

  .top-to-bottom {
      /*border-width: 6px;*/
      /*border-style: solid;*/
      /*border-color: #002929;*/
      /*-webkit-border-image:*/
      /*-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#ffffff)) 1 100%;*/
      /*-webkit-border-image:*/
      /*-webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #ffffff) 1 100%;*/
      /*-moz-border-image:*/
      /*-moz-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #ffffff) 1 100%;*/
      /*-o-border-image:*/
      /*-o-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #ffffff) 1 100%;*/
      /*border-image:*/
      /*linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #ffffff) 1 100%;*/
      /*border-right: 0px;*/
      /*border-top: 0px;*/
      /*border-bottom: 0px;*/
  }

  /* Logged in page */
.test{
    position: absolute;
    background-color:purple;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on exactly what you want for other items, but concentrating on the purple-background element it is currently placed relative to the second child of the row element as that is given position: relative by the bootstrap CSS.

This snippet sets that second child to have position: static so the purple element is not positioned relative to it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./example.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .section-topleft {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: purple;
      color: #ffffff;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100px;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    .container-fluid .row :nth-child(2) {
      position: static;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
    <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h3>Title 1 - col-sm-4</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
        <div class="section-topleft">
          <h3>This div should be on the top left corner of the document</h3>
        </div>
        <h3>Title 2 - col-sm-4</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
        <h3>Title 3 - col-sm-4</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried it on the real project but there the static does not work. The real project has a lot of more divs above it (instead of just a col-sm-4. Does that mean that the purple element is now relative to the div 'row'?

Comment: It'll be positioned relative to the nearest ancestor that has a position set. Without seeing your actual code I can't know what that is.

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I uploaded a screenshot in the main post. Sorry for the blurred out things. It should not be a problem but just to be sure :). I put the "col-md-3" on static. The div with class "test" has the position absolute attribute. Hope you can help me.

Comment: Please put the HTML and relevant CSS into your question. The image you give doesn't go back all the way to the top of the document and it doesn't show any relevant CSS. I suggest though that you first step back through all the ancestor elements and see exactly which ones have positioning and whether it is safe to remove it.

Comment: I put the relevant HTML and CSS in the main post :). I checked the positioning of the anchestor elements but if I am correct they do not have a position set. But I could be wrong.

Comment: It is working! I had to add position: unset to a few div's above the current div